# Property window in Media Foundation

Tags: c++, winapi, ms-media-foundation

In DirectShow system there is option to define and design  property window for the filter or Pin. 
Additional for this there is option to run this window by direct show API. 
I want to know if there is similar capability in media foundation framework.

Answer (score 1):

DirectShow property pages are implemented the standard COM way: using `ISpecifyPropertyPages` interface for property page discovery, the property page COM objects, the `OleCreatePropertyFrame` API can be used to get the modal UI all together.

Media Foundation is built on COM too. You are free to provide `ISpecifyPropertyPages` implementation on your own COM classes. [Stock classes, however, are typically coming without property pages](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/06101f48-7096-4b97-899e-f954a44be09b/property-page-in-media-foundation?forum=mediafoundationdevelopment):

> ... the topology objects (sources, sinks, MFTs) in Media Foundation do not implement property pages. You'll have to query the various attributes or properties that you're interested in and display them in your own UI.